# Joining two large tables which have large regions of no overlap

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I have the following join (modified from [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html)):

```
impressionsWithWatermark.join(
clicksWithWatermark,
  expr("""
    clickAdId = impressionAdId AND
    clickTime >= cast(impressionTime as date) AND
    clickTime <= cast(impressionTime as date) + interval 1 day
    """)
)
```

Assume that both tables have trillions of rows for 2 years of data. I think that joining everything from both tables is unnecessary. What I want to do is create subsets, similar to this: create 365 * 2 * 2 smaller dataframes so that there is 1 dataframe for each day of each table for 2 years, then create 365 * 2 join queries and take a union of them. But that is inefficient. I am not sure how to do it properly. I think I should add table.repartition(factor/multiple of 365 * 2) for both tables and add write.partitionBy(cast(impressionTime as date), cast(impressionTime as date)) to the streamwriter, and set the number of executors times cores to a factor or multiple of 365 * 2.

What is a proper way to do this? Does Spark analyze the query and optimizes it so that the entries from a single day are automatically put in the same partition? What if I am not joining all records from the same day, but rather from the same hour but there are very few records from 11pm to 1am? Does Spark know that it is most efficient to partition by day or will it be even more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially just trying to specify what i have understood from your question. You have two tables with two years worth of data and it has around trillion records in both of them. You want to join them efficiently based on the timeframe that you provided . for example could be for any specific month of any year or could be any specific custom dates but it should only read that much data and not all the data.

Now to answer your question you can do something as below:
First of all when you are writing data to create the table , you should partition the table by day column so that you have each day data in separate directory/partition for both the tables. Spark won't do that by default for you. You will have to decide that based on your dataset.

Second now when you are reading the data and performing the joins it should not be done on whole table. You will have to read the data from the specific partitions only by applying filter condition on the dataframe so that spark would apply partition pruning and it would read only the partitions that satisfy the condition in filter clause.

Once you have filtered the data at the time of reading from the table and stored it in a dataframe then you should join those dataframe based on the key relationship and that would be most efficient and performant way of doing it at first shot.

If it is still not fast enough you can look at bucketing your data along with partition but in most cases it is not required.

Comment: I want to process everything from 2 years and not just from a specific set of days. When I do it over 1 month, it runs fine but it crashes when I do it over 2 years. So is it a better idea to run 24 separate programs of 1 month each, so that it isn't reading a lot of data at once because it doesn't need to? There is no date column by default. Should I add a date column to both tables, and then do write.partitionBy("impressionsdate","clickdate")? Do I need to use coalesce/repartition?

Comment: Its not a better idea to run separate programs when it comes to spark programming because spark parallelize your program based on default configuration in config files and your cluster size. What is the cluster configuration you are having? If you don't have date column how do you know that you are processing 2 years worth of data.